# Pseudo-randomising data-frame in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I used the following syntax to make a dataframe:

```
story=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
valence=c(rep(1,4),rep(0,3))
index=c(rep(0,7))
df=cbind(story,index,valence)
df1=data.frame(df)
```

So dataframe looks like this:

```
story index valence
1     0       1
2     0       1
3     0       1
4     0       1
5     0       0
6     0       0
7     0       0
```

I would like to randomise it so that there are never more than 2 trials of the same valence in a row.

I have tried the following, and I can't work out what is wrong with it.

```
while(sum(df1$index<5))
  df1=df1[sample(nrow(df1)),]
    for (i is 1:5)
      {cond=((df1$valence[i])+(df1$valence[i+1])+(df1$valence[i+2]))==1||2
      if(cond==TRUE)
      {df1$index[i]=1}
     }}
```

Any help much appreciated!

UPDATE...

I have now got this working:

```
story=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
valence=c(rep(1,4),rep(0,3))
index=c(rep(NA,7))
df=cbind(story,index,valence)
df1=data.frame(df)
df1

while(sum(is.na(df1$index))>2)
 { 
   df1$index=c(rep(NA,7))
   df1=df1[sample(nrow(df1)),]
   for (i in 1:5)
      {  
        cond1=((df1$valence[i])+(df1$valence[i+1])+(df1$valence[i+2]))
        if(cond1==1||cond1==2)
          {
           df1$index[i]=1
          }
}}
df1
```

Thanks for comments!

Comment: You cant write directly `if(... ==x||y)` for example : `> 1 == 3 || 2` returns TRUE. You must rewrite the statement `if z == x || z == y` ..

Comment: If you have a long condition, or long list of values you'd like to check against, you can also use `if z %in% c(x,y)` Also, I guess the for loop you've written should be using `in` instead of `is` ?

Comment: Please post the corrected code as an answer to your question and accept it, so it does not hang unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is how I did it:**

```
story=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
valence=c(rep(1,4),rep(0,3))
index=c(rep(NA,7))
df=cbind(story,index,valence)
df1=data.frame(df)
df1

while(sum(is.na(df1$index))>2)
 { 
   df1$index=c(rep(NA,7))
   df1=df1[sample(nrow(df1)),]
   for (i in 1:5)
      {  
        cond1=((df1$valence[i])+(df1$valence[i+1])+(df1$valence[i+2]))
        if(cond1==1||cond1==2)
          {
           df1$index[i]=1
          }
}}
df1
```